# SQL table design for conversation message system

Tags: sql, database-design, structure, message, create-table

In my web application backed by a MySQL database, I want to offer a messaging system where messages are grouped into conversations between multiple users, but I am stuck with designing a table structure that caters to some of my needs:

- Multiple users can participate in one conversation
- Users can join, read, leave and delete conversations
- An inbox view should generate as little queries as possible

Now, the first requirement for a many-to-many relation can be solved by using a junction table. But it has proven to generate quite a lot of problems when writing the select queries for the inbox view.

The second requirement also proved to be a challenge. If a user leaves a conversation, it should still be available for him to read through old messages. New messages between the remaining users in the conversation should not be shared with the user who left. I first thought about using a tree-like structure for conversations. Each time a user joins or leaves a conversation, a new conversation is created with a reference to the parent conversation and new relations with the remaining participants in the junction table are created.

The third requirement also seems not to be trivial. The inbox view should display a list of conversations with a specific user as participant. Also, additional information should be displayed for each conversation: The names of all current participants, the last reply to the conversation and that reply's author. Think of the inbox view as a list of messages with additional information about the conversation they belong to.

My current approach looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `conversation` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `parentId` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `parentId` (`parentId`),
  CONSTRAINT `conversation_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`parentId`) REFERENCES `conversation` (`id`)
);
CREATE TABLE `participant` (
  `userId` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `conversationId` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `readAt` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`userId`,`conversationId`),
  KEY `conversationId` (`conversationId`),
  CONSTRAINT `participant_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`conversationId`) REFERENCES `conversation` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `participant_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`userId`) REFERENCES `user` (`id`)
);
CREATE TABLE `reply` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `conversationId` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `userId` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `text` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `conversationId` (`conversationId`),
  KEY `userId` (`userId`),
  CONSTRAINT `reply_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`userId`) REFERENCES `user` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `reply_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`conversationId`) REFERENCES `conversation` (`id`)
);
CREATE TABLE `user` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

I have hit a wall here and can't find a solution that caters to all my needs. Maybe someone here can give me some advice on how to approach this database design.

Comment: second requirement: add a boolean column `Active`.  When a user leaves a conversation set it to `0`

Comment: Also, there seems to be a lack of timestamps in your tables.  These can be helpful in determining the newest reply as well as displaying when that reply was.

Comment: Thanks for your replies so far. The current design is nowhere final. createdAt and updatedAt timestamps will be included. For now, I am still trying to get the whole system working in theory.

Unfortunately, adding a boolean flag doesn't do the trick, as only messages up until the user left the conversation should be shared with him. The user therefor has to be removed from the conversation, but he should still be able to read the old messages.

Comment: You would only include participants whose flag is `1`.  Alternatively, you can have another table (timestamp, conversationID, and userID) that populates when people join/leave.  Then if they exist in this table only show conversations prior to the timestamp.

Comment: @Philipp why not have a look at the EJabberd database it is a open source messaging system that you can download and install. I have run this database with a 10 000 000 user + network and it ran pretty sweet. Will probably answer a few questions and then create a few more questions.

Comment: Hey @Namphibian, thanks for that tip. I've looked into the [eJabberd mysql](https://github.com/processone/ejabberd/blob/master/sql/mysql.sql) and eJabberd uses rooms for what I call conversations. I will have a look into it, when I find some more spare time.

Answer (score 0):

### USERS ACTIVITY

I still would make a junction table, but with indices on tuples.

```
USER_CONV   
---------------
id_user 
id_conversation
active_flag
begin_flag              - flag indicating if id_first_reply == id_first_visible_reply
id_first_reply          - first reply in the conversation
id_first_visible_reply  - first visible for a given user
id_last_reply           - last visible for a given user, user if active_flag = false, otherwise NULL

index (id_user, id_conversation, active_flag) 


USER_REPLY
---------------
id_user
id_conversaion
id_reply

index (id_user, id_conversation, id_reply)
```

The USER_CONV should make it less painless to create inbox. Still you will need to join it with USER_REPLY, and then with REPLY.

### INBOX

If you want to make it fast, then create a kind of CACHED_INBOX, and a table with MOST_RECENT_USER_ACTIVITY. The CACHED_INBOX table will contain all the inbox data that you do not need to do any joins to fetch the relevant data, but you only have to do a UNION with the data from MOST_RECENT_USER_ACTIVITY. The MOST_RECENT_USER_ACTIVITY should be quite small (work fast), and CACHED_INBOX will be 'static'. Then once a day, or every several days at the time when the server is less likely to be used do a batch CACHED_INBOX update. It will work unless your users decide to stay in conversations forever.

### OPTIMISATION

Of course you will need to use explain a bit, to see how the query optimizer uses indexing (if it uses it at all). Mybe you will need a table like ACTIVE_CONVERSATIONS, which will not have any indexing, that would hit performance a bit. But then you would do some batch updates to USER_CONV, which would have more extensive indexing. You have to try a bit, and see what do you expect from your users behaviour, that should be one of the architecture drivers.

NOTE: regarding indexes, there is a good website devoted to the topic of indexing [use-the-index-luke.com](http://www.use-the-index-luke.com)